# Ubuntu mirroring two monitors but only detecting one

Tags: ati, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS install that I want to use two monitors with. The monitors are identical Dell U2312HM 23" that I am connecting with a VGA and a DVI cable to a     Sapphire Radeon HD6450.

After installing the driver from [their site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx), the screen is mirrored to both displays. However, 'displays' (under settings) detects only one screen (named 'laptop') for which only one, too low resolution is available.

Is there a way to detect both monitors and their proper resolutions?

I tried some options for `aticonfig -–resolution` and `aticonfig –initial=dual-head` but they don't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get it to work

- Clean install Ubuntu
- Don't activate anything in 'additional drivers'
- Install the driver from the [AMD site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) and reboot
- **In the BIOS, set onboard mode**
- Use `sudo amdcccle` > 'display manager' to set dual monitor, not 'system settings' > 'displays'

No idea how that bios thing makes sense, but it worked.

**EDIT**: I should mention that the monitors only work in Ubuntu; to access the BIOS you will have to switch a monitor cable to the actual on-board connection.